# поиск файлов в папке с++ без Win API

Tags: c++, qt

Нужно вывести в переменную String список всех файлов с нужным расширением (скажем .mp3). В интернете куча примеров но все с использованием Win API а у меня задача написать кроссплатформеное приложение на Qt

Comment: А одно другому мешает? Пишем код на WinAPI. Пишем код под "UNIX API". Пишем код еще под какое-то API. И собираем все вместе, так, чтобы определялась ОС и выполнялся соотв. код. Думаете, сам Qt не так написан?

Comment: ...Если какая-то ОС не очень нужна, то не пишем под нее, а выдаем ошибку [заранее], и в комментах оставляем TODO.

Comment: Qt [Find Files Example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-dialogs-findfiles-example.html)

Comment: как сказано выше, у Qt  есть свои инструменты для работы с каталогами и файлами.  ван нужно посомтреть на QDir и QFile